# Compute percent change with vaex dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, vaex

How can I compute the percent change of a column in a vaex dataframe when using the `shift` function?

```
import numpy as np
import vaex
df = vaex.from_arrays(x=np.arange(1,4))
df.x / df.shift(periods=1) - 1
```

results in an error:

```
  File "<unknown>", line 3
    1  1
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the x column and then shift it.

```py
import numpy as np
import vaex
df = vaex.from_arrays(x=np.arange(1,4))
df['x_shifted'] = df.x
df = df.shift(periods=1,column='x_shifted')
df.x/df.x_shifted-1
```

[image]